# Should the Windows 10 Technical Preview work in BootCamp 5.1 on new Mac Pro (Desktop)

Tags: mac, bootcamp, windows, mac-pro

[Microsoft released the windows 10 technical preview](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwindows.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fwindows%2Fpreview-iso&ei=uTbaVMOFJbDgsATkmoDADA&usg=AFQjCNEhU_V-Px6vY3kIzbCC6Rzv5rkAFQ&sig2=KLX_To0lXUCPG18XoQxdkg&bvm=bv.85761416,d.cWc) . I am not 100% thrilled with the user experience of windows 8.1 so i wanted to try this out on my new Mac Pro (the garbage can black one). Does anyone know if it should work with the version of bootcamp 5.1 on this mac pro? I know i couldnt run windows 7 because the drivers werent written for it.  [Apple doesnt specify Bootcamp and windows 10](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204048)

Comment: would someone mind creating a windows-10 tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Windows 10 works fine in Boot Camp, but the Boot Camp Support Software doesn't really launch correctly. In compatibility mode, it seems to work but I haven't extensively tested whether the settings actually make a difference. Technical Previews are generally 'buggy' too so problems may not solely be due to Boot Camp.

Comment: was this on a mac pro or a different device?

Comment: @Bob MacBook Pro with Retina display